# Reference request for Boltzmann's Theorem on maximum entropy distributions

Tags: distributions, references, maximum-entropy

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Distributions_with_measured_constants) describes in detail a theorem which gives the maximum entropy probability distributions subject to various constraints. They claim this theorem is originally due to Ludwig Boltzmann, but don't give a reference (instead they prove the theorem directly).

Does anyone know a reference to the original article/book/etc by Boltzmann where this theorem is first stated and proven?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the paper: 
[Über die Beziehung zwischen dem zweiten Hauptsatze des mechanischen Wärmetheorie und der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~leroux/boltztrad.pdf). Chapter 5 seems to deal with the theorem you are refering to, but I am not sure.

The title of the paper "Über die Beziehung zwischen eines allgemeinen mechanischen Satzes zum zweiten Hauptsatze der Wärmetheorie" sounds also promising, but I could not find it online.